# Wi-Fi scanning popup won't stop appearing in Huawei Honor 9 Lite

Tags: wi-fi, huawei, popup

A few days ago, I started getting a popup message on my Huawei Honor 9 Lite which read

> By turning on Wi-Fi scanning, apps and services can scan for Wi-Fi networks at any time, even When Wi-Fi is off.

It happens after EMUI 8.0.0.185 update.

I proceeded to turn the Wi-Fi scanning off, but the message won't stop appearing every 5-10 minutes. Restarted my phone and it still kept happening.

I tried everything I could think of:

- Disabled Wi-Fi Scanning in Location Services/Scan Settings
- Disabled location
- Made location use only GPS

but it doesn't help.

How to stop it from appearing constantly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off Wi-Fi+ as a temporary solution. See [this post](https://uk.community.huawei.com/smartphones-8/annoying-wifi-scanning-popup-239/index1.html#post868) for more information.